# module.js:684 throw err; SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 20

Tags: json

Hi im  having problems with a bracket in the .json file thx in advance also I was following a tutorial/video on YouTube, I've checked the code but the error continues to appear. What do I do?

Unexpected token { in JSON at position 20

```
{
    "Scrap Metal"
    {
        "buy": 1,
        "sell":1
    },
        "Reclaimed Metal"
    {
        "buy": 3,
        "sell":3
    },
        "Refined Metal"
    {
        "buy": 9,
        "sell":9
    },
}

 C:\Users\Galaxydragon7\Downloads\Giochi3\Bot>node bot.js
 module.js:684
        throw err;
        ^

SyntaxError: C:\Users\Galaxydragon7\Downloads\Giochi3\Bot\prices.json: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 20
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:681:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Galaxydragon7\Downloads\Giochi3\Bot\bot.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON files require key value pairs, so when you have a value it always has to have a key attached. In this case, you are not correctly defining these pairs, for example, "Scrap Metal" is a key and its value is `{"buy": 1, "sell":1}`, but you are not clearly indicating that it is the value of "Scrap Metal". The only thing missing is a colon after every type of metal, so the correct JSON file would like like this:

```
{
    "Scrap Metal":
    {
        "buy": 1,
        "sell":1
    },
    "Reclaimed Metal":
    {
        "buy": 3,
        "sell":3
    },
    "Refined Metal":
    {
        "buy": 9,
        "sell":9
    }
}
```